# Enterprise distribution Program for iPhone

Tags: iphone, enterprise, iphone-developer-program

I would like to implement a application which backs up all the internal data like SMS, MMS, videos, audios, documents, call history stored in iPhone.  But this seems to be not possible with API docs that the apple has released so far ... I have gone through the PDF of Enterprise distribution program and some of the links related to Enterprise Distribution Program,  specifies about the Remote wipe and accessing of internal data like Calendar, SMS, MMS etc .... But they didn't mention how to do it programmatically.

Does Apple provide any special privileges like extra API support to access the internal data in their Enterprise Distribution Program?.

Is there any difference between Enterprise Distribution Program and Standard Distribution Program in the development point of view?

And since in-house distribution does not require Apple approval, shall we use some other method which are not officially mentioned in apple docs, to access the internal stored data ..

If so can anyone point out the way to do it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated 
awaiting for your response

Best regards,
Mohammed Sadiq ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will not get any "bonus api", as there is no api, there's just public one, and private calls. Still, as you will distribute the app on in-house basis, you can use sqlite to get access to sms, calendar, phonebook data. I can't say for sure about other fields, as I don't know the exact permissions of the latest sandbox profile. You definitely can get access to everything on jailbroken device, but that might be not the best solution for you.

Comment: Hi Farcallar,

    Thanks for your repsonse. But I want to support the non-jail broken devices . I already tried accessing the sms.db in the non-jail broken phones where the certificate used was obtained from standard distribution program . So i couldnt access the sms.db. My doubt is that wheather can we access sms.db files in the non-jail broken devices which contains the certificate obtained from "in-house" distribution program. could you please clarify on this ..

awaiting for your response ...

Best Regards,
Mohammed Sadiq ...

Comment: No, the restrictions are same for both enterprise and standard provision profiles.

Comment: HI Farcallar,
   
       Do u have any sample link in order to access the sms, calender, phone book data .

Answer (score 0):

Standard and Enterprise are different in that Apple doesn't regulate the apps, as you said, I don't think there are any differences in development (except for what The company needs like internal server access) but there is the difference in distribution. You can't officially get that data programmatically but using undocumented calls sounds like it could work.