# difference between enterprise distribution program and standard distribution

Tags: iphone

What is the difference between enterprise distribution program and standard distribution program for Iphone

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620724/enterprise-distribution-program-for-iphone

Answer (score 6):

- **Standard:**  App Store Distribution
- **Enterprise:** In-House Distribution

[image: http://developer.apple.com/programs/start/ios/]

http://developer.apple.com/programs/start/ios/