# What is the difference between advantage iOS Enterprise account and standard account?

Tags: iphone, ios

Can anybody tell me what is the difference between standard iOS account and enterprise account? What are the advantages of enterprise account over standard personal account?

Comment: There's a comparison table at https://developer.apple.com/programs/start/ios/

Comment: 1 go to apple site you will get all details while creating account

Comment: possible duplicate of [difference between enterprise distribution program and standard distribution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954150/difference-between-enterprise-distribution-program-and-standard-distribution)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, I would like to say. If you plan on submitting Apps to the AppStore, don't bother with an Enterprise Account. Enterprise Account's are for **`in-house`** distribution **only**. More information here [iOS Enterprise Developer Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/)

Standard accounts allow you to signup as an individual **(Yourself)** or as a Company **(LLC,Co, etc..)**, and submit to the AppStore. This is likely the account you want/need.

[iOS Developer Program Enrollment](https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/enrollment.html)

**UPDATE**: Also as `@Stefan` mentioned, here is a comparison chart for each program. https://developer.apple.com/programs/start/ios/

Hope this helped you with your question !

Comment: If this is a sufficient answer to your question, please check it off as such. Thanks :)