# What's the difference in programming between Enterprise and standard licence to iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk, enterprise

If I join the enterprise development, Can I develop more power application than the standard licence. If there are some different SDK in the different licence? Eg. the enterprise have enterprise SDK and the standard have other one.

I only know the enterprise can distribution in-house application. others are for appstore.

I want to know the different in programming level, because boss want to develop a power application but the standard SDK can't do. so boss suggest use enterprise licence, is this correct way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enterprise distribution Program for iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620724/enterprise-distribution-program-for-iphone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Development wise you won't get any additional SDK. I mean irrespective of the certificate/license you have, you are using the same IDE,compiler,device,simulator etc.

Only added advantage you get is the absence of **Apple app approval** process. You can use any private/undocumented API's. You can use your own navigation methods, logos etc(which are not allowed in market apps).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "power application" unfortunately.

The only difference between the two licences is that you can develop an enterprise application and deploy it in house. For instance, if you were to create an app for the staff at your company you would need an enterprise licence to be able to distribute to your staff.

Otherwise the standard licence only allows deployment via the app store. So 1 of two things may happen.

1. You get accepted and everyone can see and download your app.
2. Your app doesn't get accepted because its only for your staff and it can't be deployed.

Afaik... there are no other differences.

Comment: We can create adhoc apps and deploy it in house...... what the special advantage with "enterprise"?

Comment: Adhoc provisioning profiles last for 90 days. Not sure if enterprise ones last a year or forever like AppStore, but even a year is much longer than 90 days. Also, adhoc is limited to 100 devices, while Enterprise program is not. And like Nandakumar explained in his answer, there is no AppStore Review process.